# Missing data analysis software

Tags: estimation, dataset, missing-data, software

Does any standard statistical software like R, SAS or SPSS have procedures or codes to analyze log-linear models for missing data in contingency tables using maximum likelihood estimation (or EM algorithm or other iterative procedures), not multiple imputation techniques ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [cat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cat/cat.pdf) package in R has the em.cat function which uses the EM algorithm to find the MLE of a saturated log-linear model for a contingency table with missing values.